# JS: 'variable' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I tried to declare some JavaScript variables in Ionic but I keep on getting

> 'variable' is declared but its value is never read.

How can I solve this issue? Below is my .ts code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /*Get info from backend*/

    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:83/totallight/api/home.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //dataType: "json",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);

          var out = "";
          var desc = "";
          var img = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            out += data[i];
            desc += data[i].desc;
            img += data[i].img;
          }
          console.log(img);

        }

      });
    }, 30000);

  });
}
```

Comment: You never use `out` or `desc`. I guess that's why your linter is complaining. Either remove them to comply with the linting rule or change the linting rule to turn it into a warning, disable it, or temporary disable (for this section).

Comment: do you check that there is something return in your success method? try to print your data and check it first

Comment: @Joseph, Yes, there was.

Comment: Also, `async: false` is deprecated. Don't use synchronous xhr requests! Especially since your making it a callback anyway...

Answer (score 0):

What your seeing is a linting failure.

You are not using `desc` or `out`, you need to reference them just like you did with `img`.

You need to make sure your using it, doing `console.log(desc, out )` will keep it quite till you use your variable.

When you are doing `out += data[i]` you are still initialising the variable.